# Windows Mobile - Get Bluetooth MAC Address

Tags: windows-mobile, mac-address, windows-mobile-6.1

How to get Bluetooth MAC address from Windows Mobile? I tried OPENNETCF library but it does not work. Any other code to get Bluetooth MAC address?

Comment: what did you try? (show code) what happened? any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried 32feet.NET ?

You can get it at CodePlex: http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Comment: I will try above and let you know.

Comment: I can't use whole library for getting Bluetooth MAC address. But, your code works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Bluetooth\MITS", "MACADDRESS", string.Empty).ToString()